# CSS Text Shadow Animations causing flicker

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with my code, it seems as though the lettering is flickering whenever the animations loops from infinite. This ONLY happens on Safari, however. I tried a majority of things and no matter what happens there's always a flicker on the infinite loop. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

CSS Code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton');

.neon-text {
  font-family: "Monoton";
  color: #FB4264;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3vw #F40A35;
}

.neon-flux {
  font-family: "Monoton";
  color: #426DFB;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3vw #2356FF;
}

.neon-text {
  animation: neon 1s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: neon 1s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: neon 1s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: neon 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes neon {
  0%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1vw #FA1C16, 0 0 3vw #FA1C16, 0 0 10vw #FA1C16, 0 0 10vw #FA1C16, 0 0 .4vw #FED128, .5vw .5vw .1vw #806914;
    color: #FED128;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5vw #800E0B, 0 0 1.5vw #800E0B, 0 0 5vw #800E0B, 0 0 5vw #800E0B, 0 0 .2vw #800E0B, .5vw .5vw .1vw #40340A;
    color: #806914;
  }
}

.neon-flux {
  animation: flux 2s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: flux 2s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: flux 2s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: flux 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes flux {
  0%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1vw #1041FF, 0 0 3vw #1041FF, 0 0 10vw #1041FF, 0 0 10vw #1041FF, 0 0 .4vw #8BFDFE, .5vw .5vw .1vw #147280;
    color: #28D7FE;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 .5vw #082180, 0 0 1.5vw #082180, 0 0 5vw #082180, 0 0 5vw #082180, 0 0 .2vw #082180, .5vw .5vw .1vw #0A3940;
    color: #146C80;
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container text-center py-5" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="col" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;">
      <h1 class="display-1 neon-text">PartyBox</h1>
      <h4 class="h4 neon-flux">Light&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Up&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sound</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The effect is intresting, but (I guess you know already) it uses 20% of CPU and 80-90% GPU on my fairly well-specced laptop - it may use rather a lot of a user's battery if left to run for long.

Comment: @AHaworth Yeah lol I'm having a page that lights up a lot with cool effects